# Change Intellij HTTP proxy from command line

Tags: intellij-idea

According to our company policy we need to change password regularly, which means I have to update the proxy authentication password.
I have a script that solves all of this, except for the Intellij proxy setting.

Therefor, my question is: Is it possible to change Intellij IDEA's HTTP proxy setting from the command line?
The setting I'm refering to is Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy in Intellij.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. The password value is stored in the file *.IntelliJIdea/config/options/proxy.settings.pwd* but it is encrypted. Otherwise your script could modify it. You might be able to dig through the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) and see how the encryption works to see if you can replicate it in your script.